# jQuery Vertical ui slider move up based on variable result

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, slider

I have calculator that performs basic multiplication and outputs a result upon clicking submit. I basically want this result to fill a vertical slider, but I can't figure out how to pass a variable as the value for the jQuery slider...

```
$( ".slider-photos" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        animate:true,
        range: "min",
        value: [resultnumberhere],
        min: 1,
        max: 500,


        slide: function( event, ui) {
            $( ".slider-results-photos").html( ui.value );
        },

        change: function(event, ui) {
        $('#photos').attr('value', ui.value);
        }

        });
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Just place a reference to a variable there that is in scope.

Remember variables are only function scoped in JavaScript, so check your scopes are correct.

Comment: so my variable is a php variable contained in a textfield with an id of "totalAmount" would I just call on the variable as 'totalamount' or '#totalamount'?

Comment: @Sarah You never mentioned PHP anywhere in your question. It may be as easy as `<?php echo (float) $_GET['totalAmount']; ?>` but then again I don't know your application.

Comment: agh! Totally thought I mentioned that, I apologize. Yes, I am using php for the calculations. I am using the jQuery UI Slider as an input method. At the very end of my calculations I have a variable storing the total amount of the calculations, for example, "

Comment: <p>Your total data usage in megabytes is <?php echo $totalAmount . ' MB/month'?></p>

Comment: I basically want that variable to be the value on the vertical slider... hopefully that made sense

Comment: @Sarah Do you understand the difference between server side and client ran code? Is that response sent via XHR or a new page loaded?

Comment: its all set up to be one page, it calls on itself for the calculations - not a separate file - if thats what you are asking. I apologize for sounded dumb, I'm doing this as an internship and I'm not quite finished with school...

Comment: agh sounding!* apparently I can't type either!